# Scala — GroupBy column in specific formatting

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

DF1 is what I have now, and I want make DF1 looks like DF2.

Desired Output:

```
 DF1                                DF2
+---------+-------------------+          +---------+------------------------------+
|   ID    | Category          |          |   ID    | Category                     |
+---------+-------------------+          +---------+------------------------------+  
|  31898  |   Transfer        |          |  31898  |  Transfer (e-Transfer)       |  
|  31898  |  e-Transfer       |  =====>  |  32614  |  Transfer (e-Transfer + IMT) |
|  32614  |   Transfer        |  =====>  |  33987  |   Transfer (IMT)             |
|  32614  |  e-Transfer + IMT |          +---------+------------------------------+      
|  33987  |   Transfer        |  
|  33987  |    IMT            |  
+---------+-------------------+
```

Code:

```
val df = DF1.groupBy("ID").agg(collect_set("Category").as("CategorySet"))
val DF2 = df.withColumn("Category", $"CategorySet"(0) ($"CategorySet"(1)))
```

The code is not working, how to solve it? And if there is any other better ways to do the same thing, I am open to it. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
val sliceRight = udf((array : Seq[String], from : Int) => " (" + array.takeRight(from).mkString(",") +")")

val df2 =  df.groupBy("ID").agg(collect_set("Category").as("CategorySet"))
df2.withColumn("Category", concat($"CategorySet"(0),sliceRight($"CategorySet",lit(1))))
.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-----+----------------------------+---------------------------+
|ID   |CategorySet                 |Category                   |
+-----+----------------------------+---------------------------+
|33987|[Transfer, IMT]             |Transfer (IMT)             |
|32614|[Transfer, e-Transfer + IMT]|Transfer (e-Transfer + IMT)|
|31898|[Transfer, e-Transfer]      |Transfer (e-Transfer)      |
+-----+----------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

answer with slight modification

df.groupBy(“ID”).agg(collect_set(col(“Category”)).as(“Category”)).withColumn(“Category”, concat(col(“Category”)(0),lit(“ (“),col(“Category”)(1), lit(“)”))).show